# (C#) How can I hide the Selenium Webdriver console application while also providing a custom path to the drivers?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a requirement to both hide the console that comes up when using Selenium-Webdriver and also being able to provide a custom path to the exact location and version of the driver I'm using. There doesn't appear to be a constructor that accepts both the string for the directory, and the DriverService for hiding the console. How can I accomplish both these tasks? I will eventually need to implement this for all browsers, so an example with any of them would be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

I actually got lucky and figured it out. DriverService is able to take the driver path as an argument! Here's a chrome example:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(service);
```

Comment: Tested it without the driverPath argument and it worked perfectly, thank you!